# PostGIS trigger to create line in one table when line is created in second table

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

I am trying to migrate to PostGIS from shapefiles and I've started setting up the trigger inside.
I manged to create trigger which are populating all of the geometry fields (length, Cartesian coordinates, geographic coordinates, intersection with municipalities and special areas) but I am stacked to create trigger which is creating line in one table when line is created in second table and populating all of the attributes.

I have three tables:
Span (shows the route, could be underground/aerial),
Fiber Cable (represents the segments for the cables),
Duct (represents the duct where the cable is deployed, only for the underground spans).
My intention is to create trigger which will automatically create duct for each cable which is drawn over underground span and populate all of the attributes (contained cable, name of the duct (termination point and concatenation of few string abbreviations (area, owner), geometry attributes, type of the duct and etc).
The difference between spans/ducts/cables is represented below:
[image]
[image]
[image]

So one span could have 0 ducts (if Aerial) or multiple (if Underground).
One Fiber Cable could be installed through one or multiple ducts.

Does anyone has idea how I can manage this?
I have GIS experience, but I am new to PostgreSQL and with limited SQL knowledge.
I was checking ST_MakeLine function but I don't understand how I will extract the vertices for the cable and generate separate duct segment).

I am using QGIS for work, so the PostgreSQL database will be accessed via QGIS.

Comment: Could you provide your current trigger code to improve on?

Comment: I don't have trigger for this. The only trigger I did for this layer is related to the geometry fields.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to share code here, I will post snippet. https://ibb.co/1mt5Qv7

Comment: Creating the trigger is not your main issue here. You need to break down your problem to come up with the correct logic to generate the new line, write your SQL code and test it then write your trigger which I believe to be the easiest part.